# What are the secret achievements in The Darkness II?

Tags: achievements, the-darkness-2

During a livestream I watched, one of the developers confirmed that there are secret achievements in The Darkness II. Xbox360Achievements also [lists several secret achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/the-darkness-2/achievements/), so I assume this to be true, at least for the Xbox 360 version.

What are those, and how do I unlock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xbox360Achievements actually lists their descriptions now, and I've unlocked them on Steam as well, so here's the deal.

The only true secret achievement is:

> *Decisions, Decisions* - Refuse to cooperate with Victor in the Interrogation

At one point, you're forced to sacrifice either Frank or Eddie. If you don't decide by **not pressing anything**, one of them will be killed anyway, and the achievement will unlock. Not sure if it's random, but he killed Eddie both times I refused to pick one.

All of the other secret achievements are pure story achievements. If you play the campaign, you *will* get them, and going into too much detail would just spoil the story (which is probably why they're hidden in the first place). These are:

- *Cheque Please!* - Survive the hit at the start of the campaign
- *I'm Just Getting Started* - Find and interrogate Swifty
- *Escape the Brotherhood* - Survive the interrogation
- *Storm the Mansion* - Take back your mansion
- *One Flew Over...* - Return to reality...?
- *Sweet Revenge* - Avenge your Aunt Sarah
- *Allies in Strange Places* - Escape the asylum with help from the inside
- *Date Night* - Protect Jenny
- *Back in the Saddle* - Rescue Jackie from the Iron Maiden
- *Step into Hell...* - Defeat Victor

The last one is also a story achievement, but for the Vendetta campaign (more specifically, for finishing it).

> *Should Have Called 555-2368…* - Survive the battle against the Hell Beast

The phone number is a [reference to Ghostbusters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/trivia?item=tr0793384), by the way. And, just so you know, there's a Hell Beast at the end of Vendetta mode. I bet I just totally ruined the complex and involved story for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the Steam version the developer can't hide achievements, it's clear *what* they are, see here: http://steamcommunity.com/stats/67370/achievements

The ones without description are the secret achievements.

<strike>I will list them here and update the answer when I know how to unlock them:</strike>

- *Cheque Please!* - I Got this one when I got reunited with fat tony after the subway level. Doesn't seem to be more than a "story achievement"
- *I'm Just Getting Started* - Find and interrogate Swifty
- *Escape the Brotherhood* - Survive the interrogation
- *Storm the Mansion* - Take back your mansion
- *One Flew Over...* - Return to reality...?
- *Sweet Revenge* - Avenge your Aunt Sarah
- *Allies in Strange Places* - Escape the asylum with help from the inside
- *Date Night* - Protect Jenny
- *Back in the Saddle* - Rescue Jackie from the Iron Maiden
- *Step into Hell...* - Defeat Victor